# Experiment Design with Known, Targeted Probability of Receiving Treatment

Tags: experiment-design, causality, propensity-scores, treatment-effect, stochastic-policy

Is there a name in the literature for the following experimental design?

Suppose we have $i=1,...,n$ individuals in our sample. Denote their baseline covariates, binary treatment assignment indicator, and response as $(X_i,W_i,Y_i)$. Overall, we are interested in the Average Treatment Effect (ATE) and possibly also conditional ATEs.

The Design:

1. Craft the propensity score, $$e(X_i):=Pr(W_i=1|X_i)$$ such that it is never 0 or 1. Importantly, this propensity score will be recorded for use in later analyses.
2. Randomly assign treatment groups at an individual-level: $$W_i\sim\text{Bernoulli}(e(X_i)),$$independently, but ***not*** identically, across $i=1,...,n$.

The obvious benefit of having recorded the true $e(X_i)$ in this design is that we can use IPTW to estimate ATE without introducing extra estimation error. I.e. no need to re-weight using an estimator $\hat{e}(\cdot)$.

The benefit of crafting $e(X_i)$ is that, based on baseline covariates $X_i$, we may have a good idea of individuals to target for a beneficial outcome (or to avoid a harmful outcome). However, we would like to validate this understanding, so the condition that $e(X_i)$ never be $0$ or $1$ is important.

In the document linked below, the blog post writers call this design "propensity score targeting (PST)" [1]. Is there any other name for this design, perhaps studied in the literature on experiment design, policy, medicine, or causal inference?

[1] https://humboldt-wi.github.io/blog/research/applied_predictive_modeling_19/efficient_a_b_testing_propensity_scoring/

Comment: Hernan and Robins' book *What If* calls the conditional randomization, see section 2.2 of the book. It's used there to motivate IPW for exactly the reason you sue it, but I don't know other literature discussing it.

Comment: Thanks! Great book. I'll have to re-read that part.